# how can i create download button in asp.net?

Tags: c#, .net

this is the Html source code. code is in runat server but also comming that error.

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Visible="False" Height="302px">
            <center>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            PERSONAL INFORMATION
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name:
                            <asp:Label ID="fname" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </br>
                            Last Name:
                            <asp:Label ID="lname" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                            </br>
                            Age:
                            <asp:Label ID="age" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                            </br>
                            Date od Birth:
                            <asp:Label ID="dob" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                            </br>
                            Address:
                            <asp:Label ID="add" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                            </br>
                            Birth Place:
                            <asp:Label ID="bp" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                            </br>
                            Mobile No.:
                            <asp:Label ID="mn" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                
                <asp:Button ID="download" runat="server" OnClick="download_Click" Text="DOWNLOAD" />
                 
            </center>
        </asp:Panel>
    </form>
```

I create a download button and i run this code of that button but i fund this error "Control 'download' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.".this my class library with code.i create  a database to add detailed in webpage. and last i covert it in to pdf.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.IO;

    protected void download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=DataSet.pdf");
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                Panel1.RenderControl(hw);
                StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
                Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 0, 0);
                HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
                pdfDoc.Open();
                htmlparser.Parse(sr);
                pdfDoc.Close();
                Response.Write(pdfDoc);
                Response.End();
            }
```

Comment: put download button in form tag with get/post method

Comment: no, it"s not work

Comment: share view code also

Comment: how can i share?

Comment: document , htmlworker and pdfwriter library names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done. button should be upper of 
tag.

```html
                
                 
            </center>
        </asp:Panel>
        <center>
        <asp:Button ID="download" runat="server" OnClick="download_Click" Text="DOWNLOAD" />
        <center>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, `<form>` needs to be outside of ASP:Panel and like the error message states you need to set the form tag with runat=server:

```
<form runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Visible="False" Height="302px">
        

    </asp:Panel>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show the complete HTML?

Comment: @KeyurKakadiya I saw your update and the `<form>` tag is still missing the attribute: `runat="server"`